# Equivalent to WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel for Bluetooth RSSI

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, rssi

I would like to show Bluetooth connection strength as "signal strength bars" on my UI for a Bluetooth Low Energy device. In order to do this, I need to use the RSSI value from `BluetoothGattCallback.onReadRemoteRssi`. However, that method returns RSSI as decibels rather than on a bar scale. I need some way of reliably converting this value into a bar scale or percentage.

While browsing through the Android docs for an answer, I stumbled on `WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(int rssi, int numLevels)`. Is it possible to use this method to interpret Bluetooth signal strength? If not, how could I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you, in the meantime, find a solution for this?

Comment: I still have not, unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

With rssi in decibels (a negative number), use:

```
int bars = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, 5);
```

to get the bars in the usual range 0 - 4.

The code in WiFiManager (from GrepCode) is:

```
private static final int MIN_RSSI = -100;
private static final int MAX_RSSI = -55;
public static int calculateSignalLevel(int rssi, int numLevels) {
         if (rssi <= MIN_RSSI) {
            return 0;
        } else if (rssi >= MAX_RSSI) {
             return numLevels - 1;
         } else {
             float inputRange = (MAX_RSSI - MIN_RSSI);
             float outputRange = (numLevels - 1);
             return (int)((float)(rssi - MIN_RSSI) * outputRange / inputRange);
         }
     }
}
```

I find that on my Galaxy S4 and Note 10.1 that the level returned is not given by this code.  It is more like the code with MAX_RSSI = -63 but not quite.  I don't know of any way to find what code is actually being used in these Samsung devices.

I do find that the result seems to be the same as what the phone displays for the signal level. However, I am using it for Wifi signal level, not Bluetooth.  I have no experience using the method with Bluetooth.

Comment: Have you tested that the scale produced seems reasonable?

Comment: I edited the answer to include more information.  Note that my experience is with WiFi, but I find it gives the same result as the phone for the currently-connected network, even though that isn't what the public version of WifiManager would produce.  The results seem to be reasonable IMHO.